# Can't start virtual machine in Hyper-v in windows server 2019

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

Recently i got a problem when I wanna start a vm using hyper-v in windows server 2019 launched in AWS EC2, I was following the link to do so (https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v).

But when I click start on the new vm, it show an error as below,
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wvIa.png)

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem or where the further i can check for debugging ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

The short answer to your question is that if you truly want to use Hyper-V on Windows on an EC2 instance, you must use a bare-metal instance type such as m5d.metal. These are the only instance types that support what's called nested virtualization. What you are trying to do is to run a VM inside a VM.

You probably don't want to do this. A better approach is likely to instead simply launch another EC2 instance. Perhaps if you share some details on what you are trying to accomplish we can better help you